# jQuery ajaxSend - which element has triggered ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I'm working on a rather large project, and I would like to find which DOM element has triggered ajax call.

I've such code:

```
initAjaxSend: ->
    that = @
    $(document).ajaxSend (e, xhr, options)->
      if typeof event != 'undefined' && event
        e = event
      that.showPreloader(e, xhr)
```

than `showPreloader()` function use `e.target` to find a DOM element.

It works fine only in Chrome, because Chrome has global `event` variable. Any ideas how to make it work in other browsers?

Comment: I don't think you need these 2 lines - `if typeof event != 'undefined' && event; e = event` as event is already passed into `ajaxSend`

Comment: Yes, but then `e.target` will be always `document` which is not helpfull at all, with those two lines it works at least in Chrome. Maybe the concept of this code is totally wrong, but I don't have any other :)

Comment: Sure, when do you make your ajax call? on load? on trigger of an event? Explain a bit more, may be edit your question with that.

Comment: I'm new in this project and I don't know all the places with ajax calls. I'm assigned to it only for some quick fixing, and I would like to resolve this problem in most generic way that is possible. Is this any difference for problem solution where are triggered my ajax calls ?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing, the global `event` and the event `e` that is created when your function is fired. What you are looking for can be found in `e` which is the triggered event, under `e.delegateTarget`, you read more about [event.delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)

Quoting from docs: "For non-delegated event handlers attached directly to an element, `event.delegateTarget` will always be equal to `event.currentTarget`."

```
initAjaxSend: ->
    that = @
    $(document).ajaxSend (e, xhr, options) ->
        console.log e.delegateTarget   
        that.showPreloader(e, xhr)
```

Comment: Well, maybe I don't understand some concepts, but `e.delegateTarget` is always `document`

Comment: You are firing the `ajaxSend` from the `$(document)` element, that's why you see it there all the time. Try calling it from another element.

Comment: @topless As of jQuery 1.9, it is not possible to bind `ajaxSend` event from another element than `document` http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document